# Combined Plot3D of two functions, each with own MeshStyle?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Can someone suggest a way to specify per-function MeshStyle when plotting multiple functions? An example is below, I'm trying to show two contours, with black and red/dashing style. The Plot3D only displays a single style

```
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 2}};
b = {{3/2, 1}, {1, 6}};
f1[x_, y_] = {x, y}.a.{x, y};
f2[x_, y_] = {x, y}.b.{x, y};
{r1, r2} = Eigenvalues[{b, a}];
contourStyle1 = Black;
contourStyle2 = Directive[Red, Dashed];
plot3d = Plot3D[{r1 f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 30}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{2}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {contourStyle1, contourStyle2}];
contours1 = 
  ContourPlot[{r1 f1[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {2}, 
   ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> contourStyle1];
contours2 = 
  ContourPlot[{f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> {2}, 
   ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> contourStyle2];
GraphicsRow[{plot3d, Show[contours1, contours2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: use `MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[#3, #3 == r1 f1[#, #2]] &, 
  ConditionalExpression[#3, #3 == f2[#, #2]] &}`, `Mesh->{{2}, {2}}`, and large values for `PlotPoints`  (e.g., 300) and `MaxRecursion` (say, 6)

Comment: or, plot `r1 f1[x,y]` and `f2[x,y]` separately and combine with `Show`: that is, `plot3d = Show[MapThread[Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, ColorData[97]@#2],
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{2}}, 
    MeshStyle -> #3] &, {{r1 f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {1,  2}, {contourStyle1, contourStyle2}}]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Plot `r1 f1[x, y]` and  `f2[x, y]` separately and combine with `Show`:

```
Show[MapThread[
  Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], #2], 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{2}}, 
    MeshStyle -> #3] &, 
   {{r1 f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, 
   Take["DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
     (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]), 2], 
   {contourStyle1, contourStyle2}}]]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `{ConditionalExpression[#3, #3 == r1 f1[#, #2]] &, ConditionalExpression[#3, #3 == f2[#, #2]] &}` as `MeshFunctions` and use large values for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`:

```
Plot3D[{r1 f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 300,
 MaxRecursion -> 6,
 PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
 MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[#3, #3 == r1 f1[#, #2]] &, 
   ConditionalExpression[#3, #3 == f2[#, #2]] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{2}, {2}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {contourStyle1, contourStyle2}]
```

[image]